# capistrano deploy to nginx/unicorn not finding application view templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible. I'm using nginx and unicorn. I've got a Capistrano deploy script that has this bit of configuration:

```
server "app.XXXXX.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/srv/app.XXXXX.com"
```

Then, cap deploy runs fine with no error messages. When I try to hit the server I see this error message:

```
Missing template dashboard/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
* "/srv/app.foo.com/foo/app/views"
```

So the error messages shows that the app is clearly not even looking in the right place for the views. I would expect it to look in:

```
/srv/app.foo.com/current/app/views
```

I've altered both /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and {RAILS_ROOT}/config/unicorn.rb to use the correct path with 'current'. Still getting the same error.

I'm sure I'm missing something subtle. I'm not sure it's missing in capistrano, nginx or unicorn configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: where does it look at exactly? what is foo? a timestamped directory?

Comment: foo is basically the Rails app name. I've been asked politely by my clients not to use their app name in the question :) Under capistrano the application name is not used as the top level directory. it's 'current', which is a symlink to the directory of the newest deploy found in the /srv/app.foo.com/releases/ directory.

Comment: whats in your nginx config in the `server {
  listen                 80;
  root ...` part?